# ggplot2: Plot in viewer does not show all values - only zooming helps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a fairly simple plot but my most extreme value is not being plotted, when I look at the plot just using the RStudio viewer (same with plots below a RMarkdown chunk).

Only when I press the "Zoom" button in RStudio does the most extreme value show up.

The plot is incredibly simple:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = index, y = value)) + 
  geom_col()
```

And is displayed like so:

[image]

Note:

- The y-scale is already extended to -14 or so
- The most extreme value is -13 but is not plotted here

When I press the "Zoom" button, then I see the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, there are several values now shown, which were previously not (around index  2405 and index 62).

Using base plotting, this works without an issue:

```r
plot(df$index, df$value, type = "c")
```

[image]

I have tried to change the `coord_cartesian()` settings multiple times to very large numbers, but the problem was not resolved.

Any ideas?

Here also the data used:

```r
df <- structure(list(index = 1:2706, value = c(-0.249, 0.153, 0.789, 
0.018, 0.13, -0.502, 2.033, 1.126, 0.512, -0.561, 1.848, -0.428, 
0.584, 1.303, -0.458, 1.472, 0.327, -0.667, -0.382, 1.945, 0.371, 
-0.621, -1.13, 0.775, -0.34, -1.567, 1.049, -0.171, -0.814, -0.164, 
-1.181, -0.552, 0.495, 1.326, 0.282, 0.266, 0.967, 0.241, -0.038, 
-0.406, 0.62, -0.947, -1.195, -1.957, -1.334, 1.09, 0.045, -1.06, 
-0.037, 0.159, -0.976, 0.065, 0.17, 0.094, -0.825, 0.619, -0.481, 
0.302, 0.234, 0.381, -1.586, -6.929, 2.127, -5.374, -0.205, 0.173, 
1.875, 0.595, 0.007, -1.373, -1.825, -1.247, -0.063, 1.872, 2.883, 
0.706, -0.36, 0.274, -0.126, -0.46, -1.467, -2.37, -0.38, 1.669, 
-0.591, -0.924, -0.528, 0.191, 1.519, -0.376, -0.819, 0.485, 
1.54, 0.569, 0.018, -0.858, 0.599, 0.585, -0.246, 0.192, -0.623, 
-0.072, 0.599, -0.242, -0.831, 0.328, 1.178, 0.323, -1.161, 0.668, 
0.501, -0.151, 0.752, 1.067, 0.484, 0.83, 0.985, 0.114, -2.853, 
-0.256, -0.229, -0.874, -1.39, -0.393, 0.154, -0.06, -0.397, 
0.703, 1.206, 0.523, 0.426, -0.38, -0.037, -0.776, -1.066, 0.867, 
0.134, 0.774, 0.978, 0.012, -0.939, 0.003, -0.879, -1.158, -0.474, 
-0.591, -0.193, -0.39, 0.439, -1.319, 1.117, 0.638, -0.276, -1.43, 
-0.1, -0.16, -0.301, -0.531, 1.146, 0.159, 0.325, 1.166, -0.722, 
0.604, -0.238, 0.178, 0.359, 1.012, -0.539, 0.142, 0.671, -0.736, 
0.296, -0.345, 0.017, 0.253, -1.335, -0.174, -0.263, 0.079, 1.052, 
-0.302, 0.049, 0.287, -0.061, -0.051, -0.222, -0.104, -0.655, 
-1.12, -0.145, -0.312, 0.243, 0.115, -0.156, 0.497, 0.095, -0.165, 
0.263, 0.278, 0.534, -0.111, 0.561, -0.362, 0.399, -1.135, 0.462, 
0.213, -0.604, -0.081, 0.657, -0.334, 0.381, 0.071, 0.118, -0.073, 
0.104, -0.365, -0.012, 0.556, -0.079, 0.033, 0.516, -0.25, 0.08, 
0.236, 0.974, 0.738, 1.356, 0.093, 0.933, 0.801, 2.045, -1.316, 
-0.358, -1.821, -0.015, 0.597, -1.214, 0.435, -0.586, -0.41, 
3.255, -1.266, 0.321, 0.541, 0.698, -0.14, -0.184, -0.588, -0.396, 
0.333, -0.067, -0.065, -0.2, -0.582, 0.174, -0.32, -0.087, -0.497, 
-0.619, 0.583, -0.535, -0.135, 0.197, 0.253, 0.193, -0.294, 0.142, 
0.079, 0.077, -0.026, -0.362, -0.075, -0.294, 0.184, -0.389, 
-0.741, -0.295, -0.333, 0.058, 0.801, 1.046, 0.365, 0.211, -0.449, 
-0.597, -0.717, -0.512, 1.038, -0.032, 0.024, -0.498, -0.307, 
-0.285, 0.28, 0.595, 0.906, 0.019, -0.269, 0.01, -0.173, -0.184, 
-0.029, 0.523, -0.013, -0.193, 0.288, 0.119, 0.261, 0.384, -0.295, 
-0.172, -0.215, 0.035, 0.056, -0.424, 0.399, 0.264, -0.542, 0.587, 
-0.293, 0.072, -0.171, 0.394, -0.055, -1.046, 0.13, 0.212, -0.084, 
0.09, -0.399, 0.298, 0.985, -0.24, 0.127, -0.422, -0.197, 0.32, 
-0.282, -0.336, -0.072, -0.583, -0.331, -0.006, 0.639, 0.144, 
-0.134, -0.233, -0.114, 0.183, -0.003, -0.267, -0.465, -0.127, 
-0.12, 0.187, -0.107, 0.335, -0.1, 0.112, 0.203, 0.671, 0.19, 
0.003, -0.303, -0.573, 0.277, -0.329, 0.446, -0.192, 0.077, -0.022, 
0.18, -0.045, 0.462, -0.27, 0.281, 0.367, -0.049, 0.198, 0.473, 
0.24, -0.597, -0.571, 0.372, 0.196, -0.351, 0.442, 1.8, -0.285, 
-0.032, 0.27, 0.056, 0.048, -0.077, 0.07, 0.208, -0.211, -0.194, 
-0.072, -0.138, 0.22, 0.222, -0.179, -0.027, -0.042, 0.024, 0.045, 
0.339, -0.171, 0.095, 0.059, -0.155, 0.172, -0.034, -0.129, -0.018, 
-0.041, 0.203, -0.131, 0.21, -0.144, -0.254, -0.167, -0.148, 
0.135, 0.158, 0.021, 0.047, 0.234, 0.015, 0.594, 0.17, 0.035, 
0.477, -0.299, 0.106, -0.264, 0.073, 0.033, -0.074, -0.424, 0.251, 
0.398, 0.249, 0.029, -0.441, -0.029, -0.136, 0.295, 0.339, -0.252, 
0.121, -0.231, -0.364, -0.012, 0.219, 0.203, -0.089, -0.068, 
1.371, 0.049, 0.676, -0.262, 0.166, 0.493, -0.094, 0.385, 0.348, 
-0.392, 0.731, 0.135, 0.565, 0.102, -0.146, -0.301, 0.183, 0.26, 
0.049, 0.102, 0.222, 0.189, -0.322, -0.186, -0.133, 0.164, -0.526, 
-1.717, 0.488, -0.234, -0.583, 0.199, -0.006, 0.337, 0.149, 0.114, 
0.074, 0.232, 0.584, -0.233, 0.171, 0.286, -0.156, -0.752, -0.368, 
0.109, 0.344, -0.16, -0.38, 0.338, -0.254, -0.178, 0.534, 0.034, 
0.222, 0.213, -0.219, 0.084, -0.001, -0.02, 0.079, 0.273, -0.181, 
-0.011, 0.005, 0.002, -0.485, -0.683, 0.389, -0.428, 0.208, 0.272, 
0.225, 0.377, 0.23, 0.026, -0.214, -0.053, -0.523, 0.114, 0.068, 
-0.179, -0.065, 0.026, 0.021, -0.07, 0.047, -0.151, 0.139, 0.223, 
0.552, -0.139, -0.065, -0.108, -0.14, -0.028, 0.054, 0.057, -0.124, 
0.075, 0.375, -0.058, 0.061, 0.733, 0.224, 0.38, 0.025, -0.002, 
0.076, -0.013, 0.147, 0.065, -0.071, 0.487, 0.379, -0.091, -0.327, 
-0.208, -0.037, 0.41, 0.64, 0.498, -0.309, 0.019, 0.134, -0.092, 
-0.085, 0.296, 0.204, 0.272, 0.553, -0.436, 0.167, 0.396, 0.187, 
-0.147, -0.081, 0.065, -0.362, -0.261, -0.444, -0.363, -0.058, 
-0.947, 0.04, 0.26, 0.109, -0.127, 0.013, -0.032, 1.939, 0.807, 
0.502, 0.454, -0.285, -0.112, 0.244, -0.214, 0.281, 0.235, 0.069, 
-0.074, 0.077, 0.435, 0.154, 0.436, -0.046, 0.026, -0.248, 0.149, 
-0.064, -0.507, 0.064, 0.137, 0.179, 0.084, -0.052, 0.234, -0.314, 
-0.044, 0.25, 0.029, 0.395, -0.14, 0.092, 0.378, -0.064, 0.143, 
0.078, 0.785, 0.261, 0.051, 0.157, -0.153, -0.133, 0.738, -0.65, 
0.061, -0.247, -0.297, 0.032, 0.037, 0.236, 0.298, 0.593, -0.187, 
0.071, 0.011, 0.197, 0.012, -0.006, -0.264, 0.06, -0.197, -0.147, 
0.026, -0.259, 0.026, -0.11, 0.154, 0.06, 0.058, 0.375, 0.215, 
0.102, -0.114, -0.169, -0.075, 0.252, -0.116, 0.045, 0.106, -0.047, 
-0.249, 0.331, -0.255, -0.168, 0.235, -0.235, 0.258, -0.038, 
0.059, 0.141, -0.426, 0.145, 0.216, -0.117, 0.144, -0.072, 0.123, 
-0.232, 0.181, -0.104, -0.234, -0.167, -0.083, -0.157, -0.205, 
-2.665, -3.327, 1.197, 0.621, -0.831, 0.462, 0.881, -0.305, -0.207, 
-0.216, -0.607, 0.84, -0.022, 0.325, -0.328, 0.519, 0.996, 0.585, 
-0.039, 0.014, 0.28, -0.288, 0.378, 0.265, 0.323, 0.064, 0.719, 
-0.509, -0.08, 0.82, 0.011, 0.222, 0.705, 0.348, 0.209, -0.263, 
0.036, 0.038, 0.117, 0.18, -0.104, 0.085, 0.092, -0.014, -0.079, 
-0.076, -0.115, -0.007, -0.101, -0.553, -0.27, 0.07, -0.196, 
0.22, -0.811, 0.443, -0.132, -0.365, -0.152, -0.731, 0.067, -0.307, 
0.442, -1.799, 0.332, 0.626, -0.002, 1.399, 0.322, -0.046, 0.136, 
0.138, 0.275, 0.241, 0.363, 0.331, -0.312, -0.456, 0.704, -0.075, 
-0.6, -0.394, 0.406, -0.819, 0.426, -0.079, -0.052, -0.054, 0.465, 
-0.102, -0.75, -0.33, -0.215, 0.279, -0.176, -0.034, 0.15, 0.118, 
0.362, -0.433, -0.548, -0.13, 0.101, 0.045, 0.625, 0.186, 0.047, 
0.185, 0.226, -0.39, 1.701, -0.11, 0.42, 0.008, -0.012, -0.53, 
-0.512, -2.145, -0.106, 0.146, 0.513, 0.331, 0.276, 0.103, 0.397, 
-0.005, -0.097, -0.102, 0.539, -0.06, 0.114, 0.565, 0.46, 0.204, 
1.477, -0.82, 1.457, 0.36, 0.213, 0.252, -0.124, -0.345, -0.656, 
-0.049, -0.4, 0.31, 0.136, 0.424, -0.137, 0.022, -0.358, -0.361, 
0.595, 0.1, -0.899, 0.471, 0.292, -0.292, -0.436, 0.053, -0.198, 
0.12, -0.225, 0.037, 0.231, -0.053, -0.392, -0.248, -1.206, -0.063, 
-1.658, 0.64, -0.129, 0.342, -0.13, -0.068, -0.913, 0.305, -0.339, 
0.966, 0.099, 0.234, 0.271, 0.324, -0.615, 0.369, 0.453, 0.245, 
-0.068, -0.237, 0.333, -0.043, 0.336, 0.261, 0.123, -0.027, -0.998, 
0.2, 0.141, -0.263, 0.083, 0.232, -0.301, -0.44, -0.078, 0.387, 
0.581, 0.456, -0.274, 0.195, 0.161, -0.472, -0.216, -0.147, -0.096, 
0.031, 0.111, 0.326, 0.034, 0.228, 0.311, 0.124, 0.379, 0.375, 
-0.165, 0.178, 0.011, 0.239, 1.007, 0.094, -0.084, -0.323, -0.002, 
-0.462, 0.025, -0.057, -0.4, 0.034, -0.06, 0.259, -0.024, 0.143, 
-0.037, -0.083, -0.792, -0.976, 0.024, -0.114, 0.03, -0.106, 
0.031, -0.105, -0.201, 0.497, -0.119, -0.139, -0.018, 0.001, 
-0.123, -0.271, 0.161, 0.411, 0.319, 0.036, 0.439, -0.159, -0.38, 
0.634, 0.109, -0.109, -0.032, 0.145, -0.238, -0.349, 0.023, 1.118, 
0.821, 0.4, 0.228, -0.712, -0.017, 0.269, 0.143, -0.162, 0.409, 
-0.034, -0.01, -0.285, -0.98, -0.9, 0.368, 0.095, 0.406, 0.072, 
0.164, 0.128, 0.266, -0.056, -0.009, 0.175, 0.463, 0.414, 0.735, 
0.623, -0.269, 0.576, -0.13, -0.03, -0.419, -0.035, 0.477, 0.404, 
-0.01, 0.237, 0.002, -0.119, 0.27, -0.039, 1.066, -1.35, -2.225, 
-1.16, -0.904, 0.306, 0.023, 0.755, -0.222, -0.023, 0.153, -0.638, 
-1.905, -0.408, 0.994, 0.815, 1.317, 0.844, -0.254, -0.063, -0.378, 
-0.016, -0.347, 0.79, 0.783, 0.44, -0.642, -0.494, -0.953, 0.174, 
-0.656, -0.136, 0.85, -0.574, -0.985, -0.563, -0.288, 0.068, 
0.488, -1.284, -0.061, -1.491, 0.976, -2.603, -1.151, -0.709, 
0.208, -0.59, -0.647, 1.812, -0.099, 0.367, -0.811, 0.087, 1.054, 
-0.323, 0.406, 2.109, 0.028, -0.209, -1.777, 1.049, 0.955, -0.376, 
-2.083, -0.927, 0.52, 0.645, -0.114, -1.353, 0.117, 0.033, -0.214, 
-0.894, -0.659, -0.737, 0.595, 0.264, -0.778, -0.135, 1.481, 
1.465, -0.886, 1.07, 0.416, 1.056, -0.13, -0.124, 0.287, 0.341, 
-0.071, -1.289, -1.555, 0.153, 1.346, -0.069, -5.157, -0.837, 
1.022, 0.262, -0.907, 0.637, -0.212, -0.204, 0.398, 0.645, -0.79, 
2.141, 0.368, -0.636, -0.915, -0.65, -0.266, 0.817, 0.351, 0.172, 
-0.496, 0.055, -0.634, 0.178, 0.592, 0.117, 0.217, 0.198, 0.26, 
0.098, -0.109, 0.308, 0.288, -0.281, 0.492, 0.852, -0.385, 1.128, 
-0.674, 0.332, -1.044, 0.115, -0.214, -0.884, 0.531, 0.416, -0.033, 
-0.734, 0.066, 1.136, -1.273, -0.136, -0.167, -0.503, 0.101, 
-0.217, 0.084, 0.303, -0.06, 0.086, 0.137, 0.002, 0.093, -0.01, 
0.002, 0.003, 0.01, -0.187, 0.134, 0.092, -0.113, 0.217, -0.117, 
0.169, -0.178, -0.471, -0.014, 0.133, -0.024, -0.06, -0.122, 
0.076, 0.039, 0.415, -0.391, -0.09, 0.461, 0.201, -0.058, -0.525, 
0.534, 1.242, 0.997, -0.041, -0.563, 0.394, 0.933, -0.778, 0.202, 
0.533, -0.515, -0.561, -0.021, 0.226, -0.085, 0.045, 0.37, -0.343, 
-0.746, 0.399, -0.534, -0.428, -0.301, -0.238, -0.006, -0.422, 
1.099, 1.135, -0.547, -0.178, -1.662, 0.308, -0.315, 0.171, 1.049, 
-0.568, 0.845, -0.413, -1.124, -0.199, 0.739, -0.099, 0.04, -0.968, 
0.464, -0.033, -0.142, -0.12, -0.085, 0.085, 0.236, -0.199, 0.016, 
-0.114, 0.276, -0.081, 0.121, -0.15, -0.019, 0.493, 0.42, 0.291, 
0.287, -0.47, -0.055, -0.377, -0.431, 0.722, -0.087, 0.146, -0.491, 
0.057, 0.388, 0.016, -0.481, -0.1, -0.234, 0.039, -0.339, -0.239, 
0.082, 0.367, 0.605, -0.099, 0.727, -0.103, -0.11, 0.195, -0.31, 
0.773, 0.381, 0.34, -0.097, 0.64, 0.403, -0.065, 0.865, 1.243, 
-0.095, -0.119, -0.53, 0.331, 0.103, 0.675, 0.587, 0.433, 0.19, 
0.487, -0.475, -2.59, 0.931, -0.036, 0.36, 0.647, -0.198, 0.041, 
0.221, 0.12, -0.386, -1.074, -0.304, -0.501, -1.347, -0.426, 
0.711, 0.065, 0.521, -1.114, -0.015, -0.141, -2.055, -2.835, 
2.365, -0.7, 0.053, -0.557, 0.942, -0.448, 0.236, 0.582, 0.642, 
-0.245, 1.002, -0.212, 0.235, 0.421, -0.02, 0.177, -2.153, 0.409, 
0.643, -0.727, 0.05, 0.048, -0.264, 0.019, 0.331, 0.169, -0.048, 
-0.621, -1.132, 0.164, -0.369, 0.466, 0.935, 0.42, -0.162, 0.11, 
0.077, -0.017, -0.17, 0.942, -0.115, 0.328, -0.305, 0.275, -0.183, 
-0.467, 0.622, 0.323, -0.118, 0.243, -0.177, -0.434, 0.299, 0.423, 
-0.222, -0.252, -0.02, 0.241, 0.567, 0.163, -0.421, -1.593, 0.626, 
0.2, -0.43, 0.139, 0.495, 0.096, 0.361, 0.291, -0.535, 0.206, 
0.395, -0.023, -0.403, 0.205, 0.2, -0.564, 0.302, 0.458, -0.188, 
-0.117, 0.011, -0.84, 0.05, 0.518, -0.126, 0.36, 0.012, 0.421, 
-0.155, 0.298, -0.088, -0.276, 0.013, -0.081, -0.078, 0.209, 
0.161, -0.149, -0.277, -0.721, 0.5, -0.028, -0.569, -0.109, 0.046, 
-0.244, -0.432, -0.399, 0.27, 0.3, 0.106, -0.117, -1.101, 0.431, 
0.01, 0.332, -0.564, 0.112, -0.471, -0.013, -0.018, 0.176, 1.031, 
0.193, -0.313, 0.145, 0.198, 0.203, -0.344, 0.081, 0.108, 0.101, 
0.29, 0.197, -0.405, -0.468, 0.736, 0.004, 0.452, -0.351, 0.342, 
-0.061, 0.356, -0.193, 0.279, -0.225, -0.492, 0.838, 0.347, -0.002, 
-0.282, 0.104, 0.059, 0.155, 0.229, -0.665, -0.694, 0.109, -0.151, 
-0.634, 0.013, 0.302, -0.594, 0.627, -0.209, 0.639, 0.101, 0.127, 
0.128, 0.027, 0.065, 0.45, -0.031, -0.081, -0.135, -0.337, -0.431, 
0.013, 0.144, -0.304, -0.056, 1.852, -0.456, -0.18, 0.009, 0.107, 
0.517, -1.907, 0.121, 0.098, -0.127, 0.357, 0.295, 0.298, -0.248, 
-0.468, 0.24, -0.147, -0.079, 0.616, 0.385, 0.372, 0.767, -0.53, 
0.085, -0.495, -0.076, 1.148, -0.76, -0.235, -1.103, -0.394, 
-0.787, 1.007, -0.953, 0.073, -0.372, 0.433, -0.178, -1.1, 0.043, 
0.065, 0.707, 0.076, -0.278, 1.12, -0.035, -0.018, -0.28, -0.086, 
-0.668, 0.398, 0.766, -0.032, -0.224, 0.006, -0.557, -0.362, 
-0.406, -0.016, 0.062, 0.106, -0.082, 0.864, -0.085, -0.092, 
0.513, 0.065, -0.404, 0.653, 0.247, 0.423, 0.093, -0.185, -0.345, 
0.297, 0.259, -0.196, 0.2, -0.307, 0.075, 0.043, -0.828, -0.048, 
-0.113, 0.052, -0.238, -0.178, 0.01, 0.136, 0.644, 0.098, -0.274, 
0.013, 0.141, 0.323, 0.036, -0.278, 0.329, -0.308, -0.3, 0.141, 
-0.087, -0.149, 0.102, 0.07, -0.055, 0.364, -0.215, -0.625, 0.287, 
-0.122, -0.243, 0.161, -0.097, 0.071, 0.389, 0.613, -0.214, 0.075, 
-0.306, 0.236, 0.697, -0.098, -0.024, 0.394, -0.212, -0.098, 
-0.066, 0.101, -0.594, 0.237, -0.186, -0.204, -0.023, -0.29, 
0.42, 0.512, 0.288, -0.101, 0.385, -0.284, 0.072, 0.196, -0.001, 
-0.501, -0.115, 0.193, -0.507, -0.322, 0.193, -0.347, 0.29, 0.237, 
-0.315, 0.452, 0.028, 0.039, -0.126, -0.05, -0.25, 0.165, -0.06, 
-0.376, -0.4, 0.143, 0.134, -0.287, -0.057, -0.28, 0.136, 0.572, 
-0.203, 0.052, -0.002, -0.305, 0.042, 0.636, -0.027, 0.29, -0.064, 
-0.223, -0.119, 0.357, -0.063, 0.104, 0.45, 0.031, -0.229, -0.121, 
0.325, -0.359, -0.511, -0.217, 0.196, -0.258, -0.279, 0.357, 
-0.255, 0, 0.414, 0.253, -0.201, 0.095, -0.413, 0.133, 0.255, 
0.013, -0.147, -0.126, -0.179, 0.254, -0.221, -0.444, 0.042, 
-0.059, -0.151, -0.838, 0.054, 0.325, -0.221, -0.216, -0.057, 
0.388, 0.197, -0.122, 0.261, -0.156, -0.253, -0.176, -0.18, -0.852, 
-0.686, -0.465, -0.907, 0.027, 0.388, -0.539, -1.356, 0.471, 
-1.507, -0.48, 0.46, -1.453, 0.672, -0.564, 0.494, -1.193, 0.409, 
-0.66, -0.077, -0.278, -0.969, -0.931, -0.264, -0.461, 0.968, 
-1.207, 1.307, 0.514, -0.31, 0.78, -1.681, -0.13, 0.684, -0.279, 
-0.047, -0.113, -0.208, 0.08, 0.449, -0.249, 0.143, -0.529, 0.241, 
-0.439, -0.08, 0.264, 0.104, -0.211, -0.277, -0.141, -0.08, 0.104, 
-0.213, 0.56, 0.646, 0.342, -0.284, 0.21, -0.121, 0.356, 0.483, 
0.148, -0.176, 0.241, -0.466, 0.058, 0.265, -0.088, 0.618, 0.674, 
-0.249, 2.237, 0.656, -1.693, -0.742, -0.428, 0.497, 0.167, -1.105, 
-0.483, 0.618, 0.322, -0.692, 0.113, 0.806, -0.22, 0.013, -0.212, 
-0.114, -0.752, 0.177, 0.201, 0.487, 0.038, -0.244, 0.14, -0.277, 
0.809, -0.315, -0.05, 0.011, -0.53, -0.334, -0.018, 0.175, -0.657, 
-0.141, 0.554, -0.948, 0.402, -0.146, -2.213, -0.603, -0.267, 
-0.525, 0.305, 0.229, -0.441, -0.049, -0.077, -0.435, 0.62, 0.484, 
-0.056, 0.459, -0.278, -0.59, 0.018, -0.115, -0.304, 0.079, -0.274, 
0.079, -0.179, -0.367, 0.08, 0.713, 0.17, 0.045, 0.713, -0.249, 
-0.367, 0.335, 0.078, -0.304, -0.329, -0.682, 0.62, 0.197, 0.43, 
-0.662, -0.332, 0.303, -0.053, -0.018, -0.532, -0.483, -0.928, 
0.152, -0.4, 0.21, -0.019, -0.213, 0.019, -0.211, 0.529, 0.68, 
0.067, -0.711, 0.189, 0.652, 0.322, 0.269, -0.659, 1.642, 0.185, 
0.833, -0.347, 0.88, 1.184, -0.603, -0.846, 0.273, 0.392, 0.491, 
0.201, 0.233, -0.913, -0.366, 0.969, -0.247, -0.015, 0.394, -0.437, 
0.276, 0.421, 0.643, 0.801, -0.314, -0.554, -0.231, -0.079, -0.687, 
-1.636, 1.047, -0.633, 1.069, -1.015, -0.218, 0.159, -0.397, 
-1.181, -0.828, -0.507, -0.434, -0.525, 0.213, 0.365, -0.655, 
0.978, -0.502, 1.258, -0.32, 0.717, -0.559, 0.314, 0.488, 0.391, 
1.794, 0.826, 0.452, 0.296, -0.021, 0.114, -2.849, 0.896, -1.395, 
-0.799, 0.723, 0.741, -0.024, -1.544, -0.002, -0.175, -0.524, 
1.135, 0.705, -0.342, -0.777, -0.359, 0.687, -0.914, 0.825, 0.328, 
-0.178, -0.205, -0.205, 0.209, 0.141, 0.205, -0.559, -0.711, 
0.723, -0.25, -0.429, 0.115, 0.242, 0.047, 0.875, 0.103, -0.622, 
2.249, -1.438, 0.41, -0.37, -0.363, -0.495, -0.327, 0.116, -0.049, 
-0.175, 0.272, -0.178, -0.046, -0.493, -0.17, 0.118, 0.017, -0.647, 
-0.453, 0.34, 0.009, 0.492, -0.179, -0.677, 0.534, 0.744, -0.563, 
-0.328, 0.243, 0.242, 0.017, -0.301, -0.107, -0.268, -0.585, 
0.214, -0.462, 0.34, -0.172, -0.361, -0.138, 0.338, 0.206, -0.598, 
0.342, -0.238, -0.33, 0.339, -0.24, 0.502, 0.074, 0.625, 0.268, 
0.179, -0.491, 0.5, 0.204, 0.657, -0.146, -0.236, 0.275, 0.015, 
-0.687, -0.259, 0.531, -0.051, -0.395, 0.313, -0.237, 0.052, 
-0.3, 0.148, 0.044, -0.202, -0.073, 0.019, -0.3, 0.535, -0.016, 
0.364, 0.204, -0.334, 0.626, 0.299, 0.174, -0.239, 0.466, -0.4, 
0.181, 0.016, 0.081, -0.27, -0.266, -0.712, 0.184, 0.048, 0.24, 
-0.366, 0.149, 0.335, 0.397, -0.018, -0.269, -0.266, -0.011, 
0.304, -0.017, 0.05, 0.399, 0.014, 0.813, 0.041, -0.015, -0.237, 
0.083, 0.562, 0.05, 0.396, 0.012, -0.206, -0.076, -0.619, 2.092, 
0.57, 0.647, 0.487, -0.594, -0.042, 0.717, -0.023, -0.525, -0.711, 
0.946, -0.375, -1.126, 0.281, 1.987, -0.99, -0.13, 0.083, -0.08, 
0.176, -0.336, -0.012, 0.303, -0.146, 1.354, -0.061, 0.08, -0.303, 
0.114, 0.174, 1.223, -0.537, -0.266, -0.391, 0.085, -0.24, -0.614, 
-0.14, -0.08, 1.199, 0.489, 0.645, 0.103, -0.558, -0.138, -0.556, 
-0.647, 0.15, 0.938, -0.661, -0.073, -0.142, -0.174, -0.078, 
1.226, -0.218, -0.364, 0.338, -0.083, -0.429, -0.394, -0.485, 
0.246, -0.722, 0.144, -0.173, -0.203, 0.05, 0.239, 0.646, 0.363, 
0.842, 0.644, 0.519, -0.085, 0.111, -1.1, 0.058, -0.176, -0.015, 
-0.398, 0.37, 0.299, -0.242, 0.145, 0.587, 0.392, 0.934, 0.833, 
-0.025, 0.81, 1.37, -0.697, -0.488, -0.336, -0.399, 1.227, -1.016, 
0.309, -0.812, 0.628, 0.358, 0.329, 0.774, 1.311, -0.954, -0.238, 
-0.114, 0.619, -0.534, 0.495, 0.263, -0.595, 1.641, -0.544, 0.463, 
0.676, 0.324, 0.518, 1.502, -0.035, -0.153, 0.997, -0.763, 0.017, 
-0.053, -0.371, 1.51, 3.497, -1.043, 0.882, 1.143, 2.191, -2.241, 
0.946, -0.767, -1.354, 1.103, 1.048, 0.125, 0.165, 0.546, 1.147, 
0.186, -0.855, 0.46, -1.367, -1.349, -0.521, 1.094, 0.061, 0.706, 
0.191, -1.618, -0.365, 0.168, 1.883, -0.107, 1.248, 1.904, 0.019, 
0.004, -1.046, 2.752, 0.361, -0.227, 0.927, 1.204, 0.182, 0.892, 
-0.961, 0.902, -1.502, -1.766, 2.693, -1.237, 0.521, 0.188, -0.572, 
-1.074, -1.069, 0.522, -1.306, -1.226, 0.243, -1.205, 0.78, 0.979, 
0.884, -0.291, -0.026, 0.672, -0.83, 0.166, -0.01, 1.813, 0.017, 
0.924, 0.152, 0.791, -0.772, -0.12, -0.553, 0.445, 0.904, 1.312, 
0.723, 0.981, -0.93, 0.877, -0.229, -0.5, -0.247, 2.293, -0.601, 
0.129, -0.385, -0.221, -0.377, 0.645, 0.854, 0.531, 0.248, -0.259, 
-0.318, 0.447, 1.076, 2.597, 1.427, 1.792, 0.996, 1.926, -1.998, 
1.126, 0.269, -3.097, 0.632, 3.423, 5.529, 6.463, -3.387, -3.892, 
-12.993, 3.683, 3.019, -2.326, 3.93, 1.834, 0.329, 1.004, -3.585, 
-3.057, 1.87, 1.95, -1.267, 0.705, 0.527, 2.597, -0.255, -3.635, 
-4.875, 1.122, 1.417, -6.162, 2.217, -0.279, 1.462, -0.178, -2.358, 
0.686, 1.199, -1.798, -2.629, -5.23, -2.212, -1.188, 4.722, 0.401, 
1.113, 3.364, 2.894, -0.286, 2.108, -1.325, -2.283, 0.341, -0.714, 
1.618, 3.225, -0.99, -1.269, -0.757, -1.011, 2.267, 1.948, 0.268, 
-2.425, 0.973, 1.769, -2.318, 4.184, 2.597, 3.314, 2.694, -0.892, 
0.891, -0.527, 1.432, 0.196, -0.142, 2.796, -6.528, 1.293, -4.763, 
1.851, -2.666, 0.24, 1.932, -0.626, 0.191, 2.473, 0.733, 3.735, 
0.94, -1.548, -2.065, -0.463, -3.822, 2.033, -1.204, -3.461, 
3.428, 0.309, 1.648, -0.722, -3.635, 0.089, -5.45, 0.746, -3.703, 
2.036, -0.755, 0.83, -5.422, 0.43, 0.885, 1.262, 5.109, 3.235, 
2.609, -0.636, -2.579, 3.646, -0.837, -2.382, 0.082, -0.197, 
1.423, -0.976, -2.098, -2.309, 1.608, -2.348, -0.908, 0.8, 1.898, 
0.9, 1.259, -1.164, 0.259, 3.652, 3.937, 0.495, -1.001, 3.851, 
1.763, 3.789, -2.468, 0.747, 0.555, 1.414, -1.904, 2.046, -0.508, 
-0.39, -4.592, 1.591, -5.473, 1.63, 0.421, 3.327, 1.549, -1.396, 
-2.864, -1.926, 2.681, 0.219, -1.35, -1.876, 0.612, 0.557, 3.103, 
-1.059, -1.843, 0.045, 0.119, -0.812, -4.937, 2.647, -1.02, -0.822, 
1.688, 2.208, -0.792, -0.607, 0.411, 0.274, -0.139, 0.279, -0.521, 
0.409, 0.592, 3.39, 0.085, 3.07, -1.666, 0.067, -0.681, -0.706, 
-0.419, 1.361, -0.852, 5.247, 0.188, 1.573, 0.803, -1.867, -0.029, 
-2.237, 3.583, 0.243, 2.493, -2.077, -0.6, -2.437, 0.355, -1.736, 
4.84, -0.697, -1.855, -1.016, -0.482, 0.754, -1.358, -4.584, 
1.272, -0.66, -2.998, -0.11, 1.9, -1.048, -0.797, -1.181, -1.845, 
2.299, -1.4, 1.849, 1.341, -3.97, 0.854, -0.049, -1.474, -0.187, 
5.371, -1.525, 0.512, -0.207, 2.091, -2.673, -2.537, 1.608, 1.854, 
-2.416, -0.879, -1.052, 1.337, -1.136, -0.922, -2.77, -3.038, 
-0.933, 1.403, -2.821, 0.338, 1.869, 3.699, 3.967, 1.799, -0.824, 
-0.608, 0.127, -0.937, -2.931, 2.219, -1.587, 0.451, 0.973, 1.7, 
-2.349, 1.026, -0.435, -2.329, 0.463, -0.288, -2.284, 0.878, 
-1.415, -0.375, -1.498, 0.136, 1.734, -0.313, 2.001, -0.504, 
-0.194, 2.286, -2.612, -1.036, 2.358, -0.184, 0.759, 0.553, -0.725, 
-1.465, 1.848, -3.497, 2.556, 3.34, 1.551, 0.801, -0.624, -0.452, 
0.47, -5.172)), row.names = c(NA, -2706L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's probably some funny quirk of the downsampling done by the viewer window because it doesn't have enough pixels. Probably just resizing the viewer will help.

Comment: Thanks Gregor! I'll certainly try. 
It's more concern to me when using RMarkdown - in a way I want to ensure that all values are plotted (especially the extreme ones). 
Is it possible to turn off the downsampling for RMarkdown?

Comment: Rmarkdown will already convert the image to a PNG or other image file, depending on your settings. I would assume it's not a problem. If  it is a problem, you can set chunk options to use a different device (Cairo devices are often higher quality) or increase the resolution (`dpi`) or size of the plot.

Comment: One possible remedy is to specify `geom_col(colour = "black")` to draw a line regardless of the width of the rectangle.